# Create linked list from elements of a Binary tree at a certain depth

Tags: c

I am trying to build a linked list, with the elements at a certain depth

I came up with this:

```
void nivel(ABin a, int k, SList *l, int level){
    if (!a) return;
    if(k == level){
     SList n = (SList)malloc(sizeof(struct slist));
     n->value = a->value;
     n->next=(*l);
     (*l) = n;
     return;
    }else{
        nivel(a->left, k, l, level+1);
        nivel(a->right, k, l, level+1);
    }
}
```

**It does work**

But the exercise asks to use this header:
**SList nivel (ABin a, int n)**

I have tried with a void to practice. But can't figure out how to make the one that returns the linked lists.

Data from structure and binary tree:

```
typedef struct slist
{
    int value;
    struct slist* next;
} *SList;

typedef struct arvbin* ABin;
typedef struct arvbin
{
    int value;
    ABin right;
    ABin left;
} arvb;
```

EDIT:

<---------------working with header in the exercise----------->
// A thank you to **Politank-Z**

```
SList nivel_(ABin a, int k){
    SList *l; 

    nivel(a, k, l, 1);

    return l;
}


void nivel(ABin a, int k, SList *l, int level){
    if (!a) return;
    if(k == level){
     SList n = (SList)malloc(sizeof(struct slist));
     n->value = a->value;
     n->next=(*l);
     (*l) = n;
     return;
    }else{
        nivel(a->left, k, l, level+1);
        nivel(a->right, k, l, level+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: How didn't it work? Didn't compile? Wrong output?

Comment: I'm really sorry, i tested it again, and it did work...
But i am finding it rather difficult to use the header from the exercise

Comment: How so? Have you tried calling your function from a function defined by the prototype?

Comment: @Politank-Z that would work, but is kind of cheating right?

Comment: What's the goal of nivel? Given a binary tree, output some form of linked list from it?

Comment: Does the exercise specify that all of your code must be contained under the prototype? If not, I don't see it as cheating, it is a fairly common practice.

Comment: It does give an hint, saying that i should care about the depth of the tree, maybe this means that i really should do this. Thank you!

Comment: @Politank-Z could you answer with that tip?

So i can select the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your difficulty with the prototype: it is fairly common to be restricted to a function prototype which doesn't meet the needs of your implementation. In such cases, it is often easier to call your function from the prototyped function then to shoehorn your functionality into the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want to build a linked list using binary tree? However, you may add a new item into your list when (k == level), then you call nivel(a->left, k, l, level+1). It won't add any node here, because k != level+1 now, so your list will contain just one node actually...

BTW, you should ensure nivel add one node into your list everytime.

Comment: Actually, the code works fine. At each recursive folding, it does check for that branch if the level is the pretended one, and it does create a linked list with the elements from that level. The problem was not that, but to use the header given in the exercise

Answer (score 0):

```
} *SList;
```

will create a pointer type called SList. This causes confusion within your code, because you use `SList *l` which is a pointer to a pointer! Change your struct typedef to just `} SList`. This way you don't have to dereference a pointer of a pointer to reach the pointer value.